# How to pass variable to writable and required fields in activiti:formProperty element

Tags: activiti

I am updating the activity flow, need to add few items to approve or reject,based on the user selection .

Requirement is: user has to select one of these items ( activity, running, biking) ,based on selection need to add the fields in Activiti form to approve.

I used the following code:

```
<activiti:formProperty id="frm_approval_activityapproval" name="ActivityApproval" type="enum" variable="ACTIVITY_approval" writable="ACTIVITY_need_approval" required="ACTIVITY_need_approval">
        <activiti:value id="approve" name="approve"></activiti:value>
        <activiti:value id="reject" name="reject"></activiti:value>
</activiti:formProperty>
    
    <activiti:formProperty id="frm_approval_runningapproval" name="RunningApproval" type="enum" variable="RUNNING_approval" writable="RUNNING_need_approval" required="RUNNING_need_approval">
        <activiti:value id="approve" name="approve"></activiti:value>
        <activiti:value id="reject" name="reject"></activiti:value>
    </activiti:formProperty>
    
    <activiti:formProperty id="frm_approval_bikingapproval" name="BikingApproval" type="enum" variable="BIKING_approval" writable="BIKING_need_approval" required="BIKING_need_approval">
        <activiti:value id="approve" name="approve"></activiti:value>
        <activiti:value id="reject" name="reject"></activiti:value>
    </activiti:formProperty>
```

The variable ACTIVITY_need_approval is set to true and other variables set to false, but in activity form all fields are displaying in disabled mode.

how to enable the activity approval field?

Comment: can somebody help me on this.one of the project is blocking with this operation.

Answer (score 0):

In default forms, you cannot pass variable values for writable and required attributes, you'll have to provide your own form impl. for that the connect it with a form key - https://www.activiti.org/userguide/#externalFormRendering

or you can create your custom form property impl following this [article](https://www.jorambarrez.be/blog/2013/03/13/creating-a-new-form-property-in-activiti/)

Comment: Thank you Abbas. is there any document to refer to implement own form impl?